# Why quadratic forms with the same isotropic cone are proportional?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a complex space with a quadratic forms $P$, $Q$. Assume that the isotropic cones for $P$ and $Q$ are the same:
$$
P^{-1}(0)=Q^{-1}(0).
$$
How to check that there is a constant $c\neq 0$ such that 
$$
P=cQ.
$$